# Refresh a button's label when clicked

Tags: android, button, onclick

I need to change the text of a Button when clicked, so I used `myButton.setText("New Label")`, but the view is refresh only when the `onClick(View v)` function is over.

Actually what I need is to change the label when the button is clicked without waiting the end of the function : what I do when the button is clicked takes quite some times.

One solution could be to force the `View` to refresh before the end of `onClick()` but I don't know if it is possible or how to do it.

Another solution could be to move what I do in `onClick()` outside of it in a new function which would be called straight after the end of `onClick()`, but here again, I don't know how I could do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to set an [OnTouchListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html) and implement the [onTouch](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html#onTouch%28android.view.View,%20android.view.MotionEvent%29) method.

In this method you'll get a MotionEvent and can listen to the [MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN).

So you can change the label as soon as the user touches the button.

Comment: It's a quick fix, it's fine for what I needed to do, but ones must be careful because when touching the button then sliding out of bounds of the button, and then releasing the finger from the screen, you have not clicked the button, but you've touched it, so the text was modified

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do anything time consuming on the UI thread. You should start separate worker thread then update the text on the button and return from `onClick` function.

For how to start worker thread that should update UI as it progresses and/or completes see [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I used Keyboardsurfer's solution, but I'll keep in mind that for the future.